# The Xcode 5.1 error out can't find some execution, when i run the app in the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode5.1

I start the app in the simulator, can get the error. I googled, but find no answer. I think I can find the professional here.

2014-04-20 15:09:01.701 AnimalTable[2507:60b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x8f33560 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle (not loaded)